# NPE when trying to return null

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

This program supposed to avoid null when calling toFloat with null.
   but I'm still getting NPE .. any help

`System.out.println(toFloat(null, null));`

```
private static Float toFloat(Float def, String str) {
    try {
        return str != null ? Float.parseFloat(str) : def;
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        return def;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's very subtle. [`Float.parseFloat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#parseFloat-java.lang.String-) returns `float`, not `Float`. The second two operands of a conditional operator must be of the same type, but you're giving it `float` (the result of `Float.parseFloat`) and `Float` (`def`). The compiler picks `float` because `Float` can be coerced to `float` through auto-unboxing.

So what the compiler outputs is as though you'd written this:

```
private static Float toFloat(Float def, String str) {
    try {
        return str != null ? Float.parseFloat(str) : def.floatValue();
        // Note ----------------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        return def;
    }
}
```

...and of course, calling `floatValue` on `null` throws an NPE.

You can fix it by making sure the second operand's type is `Float`, not `float`. Lots of ways to do that, but as Zefick [points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41695774/npe-when-trying-to-return-null/41695890?noredirect=1#comment70587833_41695890), the simplest is [`Float.valueOf(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#valueOf-java.lang.String-):

```
private static Float toFloat(Float def, String str) {
    try {
        return str != null ? Float.valueOf(str) : def;
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        return def;
    }
}
```

Comment: Float.valueOf(str)

Comment: My suggestion, for the sake of clarity, would be to get rid of the `?` operator and use a simple `if`. Yes, you'd have a few more lines of code. But it'd also be way easier to understand what's happening, whereas parsing and immediately casting back to capital float would make me think "what the heck was I doing back then..." a few months later... :) -- Well `valueOf` is the easiest way of course... Duh!